# Subtraction in array affects the result

Tags: python, numpy, subtraction

when I save one array of a matrix into another variable, when I change the value of matrix, the vaule of another variable was also changed. I don't know why.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = a[1,:]
print a
print b

a[1,:] = a[1,:] - a[0,:]
print a
print b
```

the results is

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
[4 5 6]

[[1 2 3]
[3 3 3]]
[3 3 3]
```

in this script, the value of b was also changed when a changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need read more about *shallow copy*:

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create
>   bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are
>   mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one
>   can change one copy without changing the other. This module provides
>   generic shallow and deep copy operations.
>
> - The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for
>     compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or
>     class instances):
> - A **shallow copy** constructs a new compound object and then (to the
>     extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
>     the original.
> - A **deep copy** constructs a new compound object and then,
>     recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the
>     original.

Example:

```
>>> lst1 = ['a','b',['ab','ba']]
>>> lst2 = lst1[:]
>>> lst2[0] = 'c'
>>> lst2[2][1] = 'd'
>>> print(lst1)
['c', 'b', ['ab', 'd']]
```

Now, You must use `deepcopy`, for example:

```
>>>from copy import deepcopy
>>>lst1 = ['a','b',['ab','ba']]
>>>lst2 = deepcopy(lst1)
>>>lst2[2][1] = "d"
>>>lst2[0] = "c";
>>>print lst2
>>>print lst1
['c', 'b', ['ab', 'd']]
['a', 'b', ['ab', 'ba']]
```

You can read more about [Shallow and Deep Copy](http://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php).

Comment: Thanks so much, I got it.